# ¿Como sumar el valor dinámicamente de inputs text que se encuentran dentro de un Foreach con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

¿Como podría hacer la suma de cada uno de los inputs? es decir, tengo la estructura:

```
<table>
     @foreach (var item in Model){
     <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CLIENTE)</td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="solo-numero amt" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right" value="variable con mi valor"/>
    </td>
<td> <input type="text" class="solo-numero amt" style="width:70% !important; text-align:right" value="variable con mi valor"/>
<tr>
</table>
```

Teniendo esto en cuenta, 
he logrado con javascript sumar únicamente los primeros inputs que genera el foreach, pero no los demás que genera. 
He usado esto en JQuery para lograr sumar los valores:

```
$('.amt').keyup(function () {
                var importe_total = 0
                $(".amt").each(
                    function (index, value) {
                        if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
                            importe_total = importe_total + eval($(this).val());
                            //console.log(importe_total);
                        }
                    }
                );
                $("#inputTotal").val(importe_total);
            });
```

Como explico, esos inputs si se generan en el foreach, pero al momento de que me muestre el resultado solo puedo generar en el primer input de resultado que tiene esta estructura:

```
<td>
<input type="text" id="inputTotal" class="solo-numero" style="width:18% !important; margin-right:-2px; text-align:right" />
<td>
```

Lo que necesito es que la funcionalidad del JQuery aplique para cada inputTotal que se genera en cada foreach, ya que que solo funciona para el primero donde si me muestra la suma de los dos inputs anteriores.

Comment: Esto: `eval($(this).val())` no está bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes intentar cambiando el evento `keyup` dentro de un `on`.

```
$(document).on("keyup",".amt", function() {
          var importe_total = 0;
          $(".amt").each(function(index, value) {
            if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
              importe_total = importe_total + eval($(this).val());
              //console.log(importe_total);
            }
          });
          $("#inputTotal").val(importe_total);
        });
```